# if statement only follows one of the conditions

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a jQuery if statement that has two conditions I want to make sure that the variable `square` does not equal "theImg" and that its not blank. For some reason it still passes and adds a blank entry into the array. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Boom</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="include/javascript.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" ></script>
    </head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="board">
            <script>CreateBoard()</script>
            <script>
                $( ".boardSquares" ).click(function( event ) {
                var square = event.target.id;
                var squaresClicked = [];
                    if(square != "theImg") {
                    squaresClicked.push(square);
                    }
                    $( "#log" ).html( "clicked: " + square );
                    $('#' + square).prepend('<img id="theImg" src="images/X.png" />')

                $("body").dblclick(function() {
                    console.log(squaresClicked);
                }) 
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

javascript.js:

```
function CreateBoard(){
    for(x=1; x<=9;x++) {
        var board = document.createElement('div');
            board.className = "boardSquares";
            board.id = x;
        document.getElementById('board').appendChild(board);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I added all of my code here and realized a couple things that I did not explain. My code generates 9 squares on the screen each with a unique id. As soon as one of them is click it retrieves the id of that div clicked and adds it to the `squaresClicked` array then it will add an image inside of the div that was clicked with the id of `theImg` That is why I am testing because if I click the same div twice it will add the value `theImg` to the array. With the code that I have now there are blank entries added to the array which is why I was testing for null. After removing the second condition it is still adding blank entries to the array like it is ignoring the `if` statement.

Comment: Try `if(square != "theImg" && $.trim(square) != '')`

Comment: Should square be compared against `""`, not `''`?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey I don't understand your comment. String representation can be both `'` or `"`, meaning `""` and `''` = *an empty string*, though just `if(square` seems quite enough for me.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm a C guy.  I'm venturing into territory I don't belong.

Comment: True that `''` and `""` are interchangeable,  but for readability and consistency `""` is more obvious

Comment: @mplungjan exactly, I like `""` the most, are fatty and visible.

Comment: Do not use numeric IDs - not cross browser compatible. Also use jQuery now you have it. `var $board=$("#board); for(...) $("<div/>",{"id":"zz"+i})appendTo($board);`

Comment: While true... ( sidenote HTML5 - Numeric ID - it's finally perfectly valid )

Comment: Maybe valid but so confusing and error prone to use. You will have to ask doctype and browser in all debug questions. Why is the array defined inside the click?

Comment: can you try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TP97h/2/

Comment: AND use unique ids for the images

Comment: I am still getting empty entries in the array: `["1", "2", "3", "9", "8", "5", "8", "8", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IRurIhAs/4/edit)

**Delegation** for your dynamically created elements!

<sup>(+ read all the comments to your Q.)</sup>

```
$("#board").on('click', '.boardSquares', function( event ) {
```

<sup>[About .on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)</sup>

Also to put a `<script>` tag in the middle of your `HTML` document is not a good idea, for a better reading, SEO and all other error / performance stuff put your JS if possible before the `</body>` tag.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="board"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

    var squares = ""; // HTML

    function createBoard(){
       for(x=1; x<=9; x++){
         squares += "<div id='"+ x +"' class='boardSquares'>SQ</div>";
       }
       $('#board').append(squares);
    } 
    createBoard();

  $("#board").on("click", ".boardSquares:not('.clicked')", function( event ) {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      var squaresClicked = [];
      var square = event.target.id;
      squaresClicked.push(square);
      $( "#log" ).html( "clicked: " + square );
      $(this).prepend('<img src="http://placehold.it/30x30/cf5" />');

      $("body").dblclick(function() {
          console.log(squaresClicked);
      });
    }); 

});
```

Comment: I changed my code to what you have and it broke it. I am not getting any errors though?

Comment: I removed the div part and got it working again but I am still adding blank entires into the array

Comment: Same thing it says that it was clicked

Comment: Awesome this is working like I want it to the only thing is that it is outputting the array to the console with the number of squares clicked. If I click 4 squares it will output the array to the console 4 times

Comment: @Yamaha32088 than just move the initialization `var squaresClicked = [];` into the click function! Edited to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if square even has a value (is not null).

```
if(square && square != "theImg" && square != '') {
    squaresClicked.push(square);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one possibility I can see is square is a not empty it is blank like `[space]` so try

```
if(square != "theImg" && $.trim(square) != '')
```

Comment: And undefined like @matt tests for

Answer (score 0):

The standard equality operators (== and !=) compare two operands without regard to their type. The strict equality operators (=== and !==) perform equality comparisons on operands of the same type. Use strict equality operators if the operands must be of a specific type as well as value or if the exact type of the operands is important. Otherwise, use the standard equality operators, which allow you to compare the identity of two operands even if they are not of the same type.

http://indersingh.com/javascript-and-jquery/jquery-comparison-operators

I found this for you to try ,and I think you should try regular experssion as well
I always use in my code for validation.

http://www.jquery4u.com/syntax/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples

Comment: what is not necessary here?

Comment: Regular expressions are massive overkill in this situation

Comment: Could you please bring any proof for your claim?

Comment: The only need for regEx here is taken care of in the .trim or $.trim which uses something like `toString().replace(/^([\s]*)|([\s]*)$/g, '')` - there is zero other need. `if ($.trim(square) && square != "theImg")` is all that is needed. Where does the raw need for regex come in here?